# Use IXMLDOMNode_insertBefore in C

Tags: c, winapi, msxml

I am currently developing a pure C application using win32 and some MSXML to handle setting files. My file structure resembles this:

```
<doc>
  <Element1>
    <A></A>
    <C></C>
  </Element1>
...
</doc>
```

I need to insert an element `<B></B>` in between A and C.
I found the wrapper IXMLDOMNode_insertBefore derived from the C++ method `HRESULT insertBefore( IXMLDOMNode* pNewChild,  VARIANT varRefChild,  IXMLDOMNode** ppOutNewChild );`
. `varRefChild` should reference the C node, but I can't find a way to store its address in the VARIANT structure.

Comment: I sugest you to use [TinyXml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) it is much faster and more efficient and contains many examples.

Comment: @Isalamon Thanks for the suggestion! unfortunately I work on a pre-existing code which already uses MSXML to a large extent. Also I can't use C++ which makes for the real problem here.

Comment: A `VARIANT` can store an `IUnknown` interface pointer, which `IXMLDOMNode` conveniently derives from.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you I will try that and let you know.

Comment: @IInspectable your suggestion worked. Thank you very much. You can post it as an answer if you will.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dd892632(v=vs.85)#example) under the document `IXMLDOMNode::insertBefore`, It use a `CComVariant varRef` and set it as a `IXMLDOMNode`:

```
varRef = pXMLNodeRef;
hr = pXMLElement->insertBefore(pXMLNodeNew, varRef, &pXMLNodeCur);
```

You could also do it as the class CComVariant `operator=` in C:

```
CComVariant& operator=(_Inout_opt_ IUnknown* pSrc) ATLVARIANT_THROW()
{
    if (vt != VT_UNKNOWN || pSrc != punkVal)
    {
        ClearThrow();  //VariantClear()

        vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
        punkVal = pSrc;

        // Need to AddRef as VariantClear will Release
        if (punkVal != NULL)
            punkVal->AddRef();
    }
    return *this;
}
```